# Extracting digit values from before and after decimal points in Java

Tags: java

I have 2 values

String latitude = "37.348541";
String longitude = "-121.88627";

I would like to extract like the values as below with out any rounding up the values.

latitude = "37.34";
longitude = "-121.88";

I tried using DecimalFormat.format, but it does some round up and I want to extract an exact value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function using [`String#substring`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) and [`String#indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)) as shown below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests
        System.out.println(getNumberUptoTwoDecimalPlaces("37.348541"));
        System.out.println(getNumberUptoTwoDecimalPlaces("-121.88627"));
        System.out.println(getNumberUptoTwoDecimalPlaces("-121.8"));
        System.out.println(getNumberUptoTwoDecimalPlaces("-121.88"));
        System.out.println(getNumberUptoTwoDecimalPlaces("-121.889"));
    }

    static String getNumberUptoTwoDecimalPlaces(String number) {
        int indexOfPoint = number.indexOf('.');
        if (indexOfPoint != -1 && number.length() >= indexOfPoint + 3) {
            return number.substring(0, indexOfPoint + 3);
        } else {
            return number;
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
37.34
-121.88
-121.8
-121.88
-121.88
```

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
String latitude  = "37.348541";
int i = latitude.indexOf(".");
if(i > 0 && i < latitude.length()-2) latitude  = latitude.substring(i, i+2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class and the [`ROUND_DOWN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_DOWN) option. So the code could look like this:

```java
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal("123.13298");
BigDecimal roundedNumber = number.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
System.out.println(roundedNumber);
```

Otherwise you can also use the native double and the [Math.floor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor-double-) or the [Math.ceil](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil-double-) method:

```java
double number = 123.13598;
double roundedNumber = (number < 0 ? Math.ceil(number * 100) : Math.floor(number * 100)) / 100;
System.out.println(roundedNumber);
```

Comment: I think he is specifically looking for a not rounded number, so simply BigDecimal alone is enough :)